# Georeferencing orthorectified raster

Tags: orthorectification, cartosat-2

I have a georeferenced and orthorectified image from Cartosat 2, but the image has an offset of 10 meters based on GCP.
If I am about to re-georeference the image correctly, do I have to orthorectify the image again?

The AOI has an extension of 2km x 1km, pixel size is 1.16m, and as far as I have measured the 10m offset is somewhat constant (Ranging from 9-10m)

Comment: Hi, and welcome.
Were you able to identify the underlying reason of the offset?

Comment: @RafDouglas Probably because of inaccurate georeference by the agency that provided the data.

Comment: What is the approximate extension (km) of the region? and the average pixel dimension? Is the 10m offset more or less constant across the whole image? thanks for clarifying

Comment: The AOI has an extension of 2km x 1km, pixel size is 1.16m, and as far as I have measured the 10m offset is somewhat constant (Ranging from 9-10m). Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-orthorectifying would of course be ideal, expecially if you can start from the original image, but given that the offset is constant (+/- 1 pixel), probably re-georeferncing is still acceptable and yields more or less the same precision.

Comment: Guess I will re-georeference and see the results, thanks a lot.